# How do I use glClipControl[EXT] in OpenGLES?

Tags: opengl-es, renderdoc

Can't figure out how do I use `glClipControl` or `glClipControlEXT` in OpenGLES? Which one is available in OpenGLES? Does it go from some extension?

Why isn't it listed here https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/ ?

I am working on RenderDoc's fork and need to make the following code work with OpenGLES:

```
if(HasExt[ARB_clip_control])
{
  GL.glGetIntegerv(eGL_CLIP_ORIGIN, (GLint *)&ClipOrigin);
  GL.glGetIntegerv(eGL_CLIP_DEPTH_MODE, (GLint *)&ClipDepth);
}
else
{
  ClipOrigin = eGL_LOWER_LEFT;
  ClipDepth = eGL_NEGATIVE_ONE_TO_ONE;
}

// ...

if(GL.glClipControl && HasExt[ARB_clip_control])
  GL.glClipControl(ClipOrigin, ClipDepth);
```

but it is not clear enough what condition should I check instead of `HasExt[ARB_clip_control]` in OpenGLES.

My first idea was to probably check something like `IsGLES && GLCoreVersion >=0`, but looks like it is not quite correct.

The only thing that I know for sure is that `HasExt[ARB_clip_control]` is false in OpenGLES and `glClipControl` simply is not handled by this code.

Comment: Do you have any indication that this method is available at all in OpenGL-es?

Comment: @BOL I have some capture file (*.rdc RenderDoc format) from an Android app containing `glClipControlEXT`, so some Android app calls it somehow with OpenGLES.

Comment: Ah ok, so you are talking about an EXT extension (not a ARB extension). What does `HasExt[EXT_clip_control]` state? Btw, here is the extension you are looking for: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_clip_control.txt

Comment: @BDL yes, `HasExt[EXT_clip_control]` is true in OpenGLES with this capture file.